# How to use cut command to shorten a file name, and use it inside a bash script?

Tags: bash, unix, cut

I would like to use the text of a variable, fileroot, as an input for another command. However, fileroot is based upon the name of another file in the same directory.

So far, I have

```
for file in *on.nii; do 
    fileroot="cut -c 1-78 ${file}"
done
```

I am getting an unrecognised option for the -c command. Any ideas on how to limit the `{file}` to only 78 characters?

Comment: Are you trying to cut `${file}` itself or its contents?  Also, why `"`  and not the (presumably correct) backticks or `$()`?

Comment: say this instead: fileroot=$(cut -c 1-78 ${file})

Comment: Sorry - I'm new to bash - what are the differences between those?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply address the string, instead of using `cut`:

```
for file in *on.nii; do 
    fileroot="${file:0:78}"
done
```